# What does "compatibility level" mean in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Reading official docs about [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function, at the begining of the doc there is a note:

> Note
>
> The **STRING_SPLIT** function is available only under compatibility level
>   130 and above. If your database compatibility level is lower than 130,
>   SQL Server will not be able to find and execute **STRING_SPLIT** function.
>   To change the compatibility level of a database, refer to View or
>   Change the Compatibility Level of a Database. Note that compatibility
>   level 120 might be default even in new Azure SQL Database.

So, what does *compatibility level* mean?

Comment: It's the version of SQL Server that your database uses. If you have multiple versions of SQL Server installed ( e.g. 2012/2014/2016 / STRING_SPLIT requires 2016/ level 130 ) you can change which version you would like the database to run under--which will enable/disable certain functionality. In SSMS if you right-click on your database, choose Properties and click Options. You can change your compatibility level there. Don't do this blindly. Changing your database level could remove some features/legacy code you are using.

Comment: To add to @CriticalError information, they equivocate to SQL Server versions. Compatibility Level 130 = 2016, 120 = 2014, 110 = 2012, etc.

Comment: Ooooh, I see... Well, now there is clear. Thanks @CriticalError and Jacob

Comment: The SQL Server version is the same regardless of database compatibility level. Database compatibility level allow one to upgrade to a newer SQL Server version yet preserve some legacy behavior at the database level until the application can be remediated. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level) for specifics on how the behaviors differ by compatibility levels.

Comment: @CriticalError - which versions are available for compatibility level entirely depend on the specific version of SQL Server you're interacting with. It has nothing to do with which versions are *installed*. E.g. install SQL Server 2008 on a blank box and you'll get support for the 2000 and 2005 compatibility levels.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Agreed and I understand that it goes backward, but it does matter. Having SQL Server 2014 installed will not give access to level 130.

Answer (score 3):

Compatibility Level refers to the way SQL Server operates in relation to a specific version of SQL Server.

Let's say for example, you have an application running well on SQL Server 2012, but you need to upgrade to SQL Server 2019 because support is ending soon. Everything runs great on SQL Server 2012 and the application has not been updated in many years. So, it's unclear how it might perform running on SQL Server 2019, or if it'll even work at all.

To ease the transition when you migrate to SQL Server 2019, you could consider leaving the database in SQL Server 2012 compatibility level, to avoid any unforeseen performance issues that may be introduced by the way the SQL engine and optimizer work in SQL Server 2019. Essentially, to the application, it's as if you're still running SQL Server 2012.

Now, the downside is that you can also not take advantage of the newer features that have been introduced since SQL Server 2012, such as `STRING_SPLIT`.